# With InDesign, how can I copy and paste layers to be designated for a specific page?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have 4 pages side by side and I have turned on "Paster Remembers Layers". I want to copy the layers from one page and paste them onto another page, where I can edit those new layers individually, I want to be able to delete or hide some layers depending on the page Im working on, while leaving those same layers as they were on other pages.

The problem is when I select all content on one page, copy it, double click a different page, or select that page in the pages menu, and then paste the layers, the content is duplicated within the existing layers instead of creating new layers for that new page. Its as if the layers are global across all pages.

How can I duplicate or copy & paste layers across pages so that the layers exists on each page individually?

Comment: @Scott well perhaps that should be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>My previous comment was incorrect. I think I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do.</sup>

Layers are relative to pages. If you have, say 3 pages and 1 layer, you can have different content on each page on the same layer. In fact, this is how InDesign works by default.

You open a new document with 3 pages and by *default* there's only one layer. Place something on page 1, then move to page 2 that object is not present. Place something on page 2 and move back to page 1 -- the page 2 object is not visible. However, both objects on page 1 and 2 are *also* on Layer 1. Changing pages alters the visible content on Layer 1.

In your scenario, I don't think you would copy/paste layers across pages, you copy/paste the *content* across *pages*.

In short... I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. Layers in InDesign aren't like layers in Photoshop or Illustrator. They operate on a hierarchy -- Document > Master Page > Page > Layer -- You can easily have content on the same layer which shows/hides based upon the page being currently viewed.

If you want common elements to be visible on some pages, but not others, that is what Master Pages are for.